# What makes a connection reusable

Tags: java, keep-alive, persistent

I saw this description in the Oracle website: 
"Since TCP by its nature is a stream based protocol, in order to reuse an existing connection, the HTTP protocol has to have a way to indicate the end of the previous response and the beginning of the next one. Thus, it is required that all messages on the connection MUST have a self-defined message length (i.e., one not defined by closure of the connection). Self demarcation is achieved by either setting the Content-Length header, or in the case of chunked transfer encoded entity body, each chunk starts with a size, and the response body ends with a special last chunk."

See [Oracle doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/net/http-keepalive.html)

I don't know how to implement, can someone give me an example of Java implementation ?

Comment: What are you trying to implement?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to implement "self-demarcation" in the same way as HTTP does it:

- the HTTP 1.1 specification defines how it works,
- the source code of (say) the Apache HTTP libraries are an example of its implementation.

In fact, it is advisable NOT to try and implement this (HTTP) yourself from scratch.  Use an existing implementation.

---

On the other hand, if you simply want to implement your own ad-hoc self-demarcation scheme, it is really easy to do.

- The sender figures out the size of the message, in bytes or characters or some other unit that makes sense.
- The sender sends a the message size, followed by the message itself.

At the other end:

- The receiver reads the message size, and then reads the requisite number of bytes, characters, to form the message body.

An alternative is to for the sender to send the message followed by a special end-of-message marker.  To make this work, either you need to guarantee that no message will contain the end-of-message marker, or you need to use some sort of escaping mechanism.

Implementing these schemes is simple Java programming.

---

> What makes a connection reusable

That is answered by the text that you quoted in your Question.